# how can achieve the same result through sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table tblEmpBatch

```
Username  Filename  BatchId
 a          f1      1
 b          f2      1
 c          f3      2  
 d          f4      2
```

I want output like

```
Username  Filename  BatchId
 a,b       f1,f2      1
 c,d       f3,f4      2
```

How can I write sql query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (To use it in your table change the table name as needed and check the column name)

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE2(Username varchar(10), filename VARCHAR(10), batchid INT) 
INSERT INTO #TABLE2 VALUES('a' , 'f1' , 1)
INSERT INTO #TABLE2 VALUES('b' , 'f2' , 1)
INSERT INTO #TABLE2 VALUES('c' , 'f3' , 2)
INSERT INTO #TABLE2 VALUES('d' , 'f4' , 2)

select
    Username = 
        stuff((
            select
                ', ' + t2.Username
            from #table2 t2
            where
                t2.batchid = t1.batchid
            group by t2.Username
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
        ), 1, 2, ''),
    filename = 
            stuff((
                select
                    ', ' + t2.filename
                from #table2 t2
                where
                    t2.batchid = t1.batchid
                group by t2.filename
                for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
            ), 1, 2, ''), batchid
from #table2 t1 group by batchid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT   
  GROUP_CONCAT(Username) AS Username,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Filename) AS Filename,
FROM tbl
GROUP BY BatchId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (username varchar(1),Filemname varchar(10),Batchid int)
insert into @t (username,Filemname,Batchid)values ('a','f1',1)
insert into @t (username,Filemname,Batchid)values ('b','f2',1)
insert into @t (username,Filemname,Batchid)values ('c','f3',2)
insert into @t (username,Filemname,Batchid)values ('d','f4',2)


select distinct t.[Batchid],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.username
         from @t t1
         where t.[Batchid] = t1.[Batchid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') username,
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.Filemname
    from @t t1
    where t.[Batchid] = t1.[Batchid]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,2,'') Filemname

from @t t;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will be work fine

```
Select distinct ST2.BatchId as BatchID, (
              Select ST1.Filename + ',' AS[text()]

                From tblEmpBatch ST1
                Where ST1.BatchId= ST2.BatchId
                ORDER BY ST1.BatchId
                For XML PATH ('')
             )[FileName]
      , 

              (
              Select ST1.Username + ',' AS [text()]

                From tblEmpBatch ST1
                Where ST1.BatchId= ST2.BatchId
                ORDER BY ST1.BatchId
                For XML PATH ('')
             )[UserName]
        From dbo.tblEmpBatch ST2
```